# Reset search results and clear the search text using a button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, inputtext

I want to clear the inputtext used to search, and clear all search results using a commandbutton. I tried the following on the 'Reset' button I added but it only clears the inputtext and the search results are not clearing.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" Rendered="true">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!ReportSearchString}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchReports}" reRender="ReportSearchResults, "/> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!BackToCreateFeedPage}"/>&nbsp;
                    <apex:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset();return false;"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        <apex:pageBlockSection id="ReportSearchResults">
                <apex:outputText value="{!warningMessage}" rendered="{!!showTable}" />
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!reportList}" var="item" rendered="{!showTable}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Report Name" >
                        <apex:commandLink value="{!item.Name}" action="{!BackToCreateFeedPage}">
                            <apex:param value="{!item.Id}" name="SelectedReport" assignTo="{!selectedReportId}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
```

This is my search function, it works fine. I need to clear the results of this search on clicking 'Reset' button.

```
 public void searchReports()
    {
        showTable = false;      
        reportList = new List<Report>(); 
        reportSearchResult = new Map<Id, Report>(); 
        selectedReport = new Report();
        if((ReportSearchString != null && ReportSearchString != '') && ReportSearchString.length() >= 3)
        {
            reportSearchResult = new Map<Id, Report>([Select Id, Name From Report Where Name Like :'%'+ReportSearchString+'%' limit 2000]);

            warningMessage = 'No Result Found';
        }
        else
        {
            warningMessage = 'Search text should have atleast 3 characters';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following technique with an actionsupport worked. I rerender the Pageblock.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Please Search and Select a Source Report" id="pbBlock" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" Rendered="true" id="panelId">
                        <apex:inputText value="{!ReportSearchString}" />
                        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchReports}" reRender="ReportSearchResults, "/> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                        <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!BackToCreateFeedPage}"/>&nbsp;
                        <apex:outputPanel style="padding:4.5px;" styleClass="btn" >
                            Reset
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!reset}" rerender="pbBlock" />
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!BackToCreateFeedPage}"/> -->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Method,

```
public pageReference reset()    {
      showTable = false;
      this.ReportSearchString = '';
      return null;    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Page:
have a id on first `outputpanel` and `pageblocktable` and rerender them after resetting the search string and search results.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Reset" action="{!reset}" rerender="OutPutPanelId PageBlockTableId"/>
```

Controller:

```
public void reset(){
   ReportSearchString = '';
   if(reportList != null){
       reportList.clear();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. For some reason it did not work as expected. I tried using an actionsupport and it worked!

Comment: Glad you managed to make it work. Sorry for the untested code, just wanted to give you the idea.

Comment: No worries! Thanks so much for the support, your answer lead me to the correct path! Regards :)