# Action function in Firefox doesn't work

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

My function to clear the results of search, works in Chrome, IE, ME, but, in Firefox doesn't works.

---

My action function:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callClean" action="{!cleanResults}" reRender="pageblockid" />`
```

My class:

```
public void cleanResults(){
        integer deleteRegistros = registro.size();
        if(deleteRegistros != 0){
            for(integer i=0; i < deleteRegistros; i++){
                registro.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Nothing happens? A Visualforce error? Does the "console" show any errors (press F12, look for red messages)? We want to help you, but this question is fairly vague, especially for something that should be straight forward.

Comment: As an aside, your entire function could have been written as: `public void cleanResults() { registro.clear(); }`

Comment: When I run the action function, nothing happens, the page is rendered and stay the same way. I tried your method and doesn't work , same problem ...

Comment: Thanks for everyone, I found a answer to my problem : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51954/reset-search-results-and-clear-the-search-text-using-a-button-click